# Text EmailTemplate...In PlainTextBody....{!User.FirstName}....Name Not Displayed

Tags: email-template

I have Query Regarding Simple Text Email Template.Here I have VF Page And Controller Class in that VF page I want to load Predefined Text Email Template....

Here is the VF Page Code....

```
<apex:page controller="EmailTemplateTestController">

<apex:form >
    <apex:actionFunction name="send" action="{!send}" rerender="bodyField">
          <apex:param name="c" value="" assignTo="{!emailBodyText}"/>
    </apex:actionFunction>

    <apex:pageBlock title="Compose Email" id="MainPage">
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel >To</apex:outputLabel>    
            <apex:inputText title="sending address" value="{!ToList}" id="ToField" styleClass="ToField" style="height:16px; width:200px;"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <span>Body</span>
                <apex:inputTextarea value="{!templateBody}" style="width:400px ; height:400px"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>   
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:commandButton value="Send" action="{!send}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

And Controller Class Regarding VF Page....

```
public class EmailTemplateTestController{

public string ToField{get;set;}
public string ToList{get;set;}
public string ccList{get;set;}
public string emailBodyText{get;set;}
public string emailSubject{get;set;}
public EmailTemplate Templates{get;set;}
public String templateBody {get;set;}        
public string Community_Name{get;set;}

public EmailTemplateTestController()
{
     emailBodyText = '';
     Community_Name = 'customer';
     Templates = [Select Id, Name, IsActive,body,Folder.Name From EmailTemplate Where Name = 'VFEmailTemp' LIMIT 1];
     templateBody = Templates.body ;

}

public PageReference send()
{

  List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstMsgs = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
  List<string> ToAddresses = ToList.split(',');

  system.debug('-----ToAddresses --'+ToAddresses );

  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
  mail.setToAddresses(ToAddresses); 
  mail.setTargetObjectId('00590000001IIC3');             //  User ID

  mail.setTemplateId(Templates.Id);
  mail.setHtmlBody(templateBody );
  mail.saveAsActivity = false;
  //mail.setHtmlBody(templateBody);
  lstMsgs.add(mail);

 // system.debug('-----lstMsgs--'+lstMsgs);

  try{
       Messaging.sendEmail(lstMsgs);
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     system.debug('exception--'+e);
  }

  return null;

}

}
```

Here I want to Display In Template...

```
 Hi Amezon113(user FirstName)
```

For that here i made template and id was used in the controller,here is the snapshot...

[image]

But in the output of VF page it displayed same as Binding in Template.......look output

[image]

Here I want to Display User's FirstName so what can i do for that,Please Any one Help Me to solve this query regarding Email Template....

Comment: Hello It's Urgent....Please Help me to find solution of above mention Email Template in VF Page.....

Comment: Hello Please Help me,I can't find the solutions......Please......

Answer (score 3):

First of all let's have a quick look at the documentation of [`Messaging.SingleEmailMessage`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm) that explains the problem with your approach. Basically when constructing an email you can use either `setHtmlBody` or `setTemplateId`, never both. As you can see in your solution, template is not evaluated, because it's covered by the custom message on `setHtmlBody`. Salesforce's templating engine is provided *only* for static Email Templates that are provided by `setTemplateId`, thus you cannot use dynamic templates out of the box.

To make the answer constructive, let me suggest 3 approaches that you could follow to achieve dynamicity of emails:

1. The mechanism of [Visualforce Email Templates](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_email_templates_intro.htm) is quite powerful. In fact it even allows to [attach an APEX Controller to a template](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_email_templates_with_apex.htm). It's a way to go, if you require to customize only certain parts of a message right before sending - for example to add additional notes or add complex logic for some gaps.
2. More generic approach is implementing own templating engine in APEX. Potentially you could use `String.replace` method to fill in gaps of a dynamic template with the following simple pattern:

   ```
   String customTemplate = 'Hello {!User.FirstName} {!User.LastName}!';
   for(String fieldName : new String[]{ 'FirstName', 'LastName'}) {
       String fieldValue = String.valueOf(anUser.get(fieldName));
       customTemplate.replace('{!User.' + fieldName + '}', fieldValue);
   }
   ```
3. Lastly you could use my simple library [Salesforce APEX Templates](https://github.com/andrzejchodor/salesforce-apex-templates) fills in the gaps for you, what gives flexibility near to the original Email Templates:

   ```
   String emailBody = new Template('Hello {!User.FirstName} {!User.LastName}!')
       .evaluate(anUser);
   ```